# Phone only charges when plugged into AC adapter or computer

Tags: charging, samsung-galaxy-ace-2

I have a Samsung Galaxy Ace 2 x. It only charges when plugged in to the AC adapter and my laptop, and doesn't charge using battery packs or in the car. I use the same cord for everything. Why is this?

Comment: Not enough current?

Comment: I agree with agent, you would need **at least** 1A charger if you want to charge smartphones nowadays. Even more 2A for a tablet. Your PC cannot supply that much specially if its below USB 3.0 standard.

Comment: my pc is 3.0 usb

Answer (score 0):

Open your car charger and at the back of the USB socket solder together the two middle contacts. These are the D- and D+ signals. Most Galaxy phones don't like an open circuit there, so now you have made a nice loop. Info: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Serial_Bus